# How to create a folder in Phone Storage with Name of our android app?

Tags: android, storage, development-environment, android-context, mediastore

I want to create a folder with my app name directly in phone storage like WhatsApp and Telegram where I can build custom subfolders inside that folder.

There are some things that I know:
1. getExternalFilesDirs make folder inside Phone Storage/Android/com.example.app_name/
2. getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated in Android Q so it cannot be used in Android Q

I want something like Phone Storage/App_Name. Please provide how to do this.

Comment: That's not possible on Android 10+. Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and allow the user to choose where you place your content.

Comment: I have Android 10 in my Poco F1. But Whatsapp still exists in the main phone storage directory. How is it possible?

Comment: If WhatsApp was preinstalled, the device manufacturer can do what it wants. Also, for another few months, you can use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to opt out of Android 10's "scoped storage" and have things work the way they had from Android 4.4-9. However, once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to 29 or higher, `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will no longer work on Android 10.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answering my question. Also is there some tutorial or link where I can see example of storage access framework?

Comment: I wrote a long series of blog posts, [starting here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html), on "scoped storage" alternatives, including the Storage Access Framework. You will also find it in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files).